# MLSAG adaptation?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures

I understand that the main reason why the RCTTypeFull scheme is not applied to multi-input transactions is that the true signing keys in the MLSAG algorithm are on the same row, which impacts traceability (one input identified, all identified).

Has anybody invested time in trying to reformulate the MLSAG algorithm to circumvent this limitation?
At first sight it shouldn't be terribly difficult ...

I know that StringCT is coming, but in the meantime the generalization would cut space needs by half ....

Comment: Can you please provide more clarity on your "first sight" impression?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of re-shuffling indexes?
It would probably be more tricky to put on paper than to actually implement it in the code, I think

Comment: If you shuffle indexes, your commitment sum will be incorrect.